# How to change hexadecimal data format in python?

Tags: python, format, dataformat

i am beginner in python sorry... i have a series of data like this

```
b'B\x86\xfe\xca\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x08\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

which i convert to hex

```
['0x42', '0x86', '0xfe', '0xca', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x4', '0x8', '0x0', '0x0', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff']
```

but i want to turn it into something like this

```
0x4286feca, 0x00004800, 0xffffffff
```

how can i do this?
thanks so much

My code below >

```
brA = [b for b in struct.unpack(str(len(data))+'B',temp)]
sent_val = [str(hex(v)) for v in brA]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: binary/hex string conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238002/python-binary-hex-string-conversion)

Comment: Note that CPython can't output `bytes` or `int` as hex like you want. You can, of course, create a `str` that looks like hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = b'B\x86\xfe\xca\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x08\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'

dwords_as_str = ["0x" + data[i:i+4].hex() for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
print(dwords_as_str)
```

Output:

```
['0x4286feca', '0x00000000', '0x04080000', '0xffffffff']
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions